# Can't debug on Simulator 3.2 anymore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator

I have recently updated XCode (3.2.4) and the SDK (4.1).

When debugging I can only debug using:

- iPad Simulator 3.2
- iPhone Simulator 4.0
- iPhone Simulator 4.0

How do I use the iPhone Simulator for 3.2? Is it available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 3.2 never ran on the iPhone. It was iPad-only. And Apple considers iOS 3.1 too old to maintain support for.

Comment: Ah OK Thanks. So to test apps on older iPhones, I have to pretend they're iPads?

Comment: No, to test on older phones you need a physical device with the older OS installed on it.

Comment: Or if you can find an older version of XCode you can use the simulator with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no iOS 3.2 for iPhones.  Only iPhone OS 3.1.x and lower, and iOS 4.0 an up.

To test on iPhone OS 3.1.3 (or earlier), you will need an actual device running that OS version.  Many developers buy a used older model iPod Touch for just this purpose.

Apple is no longer accepting apps that run on iPhone OS versions prior to 3.0.